# Powershell Output SQL results to another SQL Database

Tags: sql, sql-server, powershell, export-to-csv

I have done this so far using export-csv then reading the csv back into another SQL DB, but the data is not the same, it is scrubbed of the type of column it is and things like bit type ( 1 or 0) end up as true or false in the other DB

Is there an easy way to issue a select statement on one SQL server, and write the results to another SQL server, I would need to create the table on the second new server as per the results of the select statement.

I hope this makes sense.

```
$Global:SqlAdapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter($Global:SqlCmd)
$Global:filename = "$cfgdir\$svr-$db-$date.csv"
$DataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
$SqlAdapter.Fill($DataSet) >$null| Out-Null
$DataSet.Tables[0] | export-csv $Global:filename -NoTypeInformation
```

Instead of exporting the data to a csv, I would prefer to direct it right into the other Database if possible.

Comment: Why is this tagged with both MySQL and SQL Server?  Are you moving your data between different database products?

Comment: Why don't you just use linked server between each SQL Server? Using PowerShell requires you pull it from one source before you can put it in the destination.

Comment: Because the end SQL servers belong to different businesses and will not allow a link. We must collect manually. I trying to make it easier to collect the data and consolidate it, rather than connecting to each server, run the command and save to csv.
So far I can loop through each server and output the query to a .csv for each server. but ultimately would like to consolidate the data into our own SQL DB for easier use.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the [SqlServer Powershell module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sqlserver/?view=sqlserver-ps)? It has 2 cmdlets that might help, Read-SqlTableData and Write-SqlTableData. If you're transferring between 2 SQL Server databases, then I would start there. If it's a ton of data, then there are more efficient ways of doing this by using [bcp](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/bcp-utility).

Comment: How do i use this?
The powershell script does not recognize Write-SqlTableData

Comment: This requires that you have at least Powershell 5 and the SqlServer module installed. Instructions can be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-ps-module

Comment: I need this to work on many machines where the user may not have any experience with powershell, installing a module may be a big hinderance.

Comment: I need this to work on many machines where the user may not have any experience with PS, installing a module may be a big issue.

I have searching online and still coming up short.

we have a few select statements and we need results of that select statement to be pushed to another SQL server, and the table created to match the output of the select statement.

the way i have it now, a CSV is created and all flds are genrl fields, then the table is created in SQL with matching headers and then data cpied into the tble, but all fields are varchar, I need to cpy the field type over as well.

Comment: So these databases reside on the client system itself? And the client has to be the one that runs this?

Comment: No, I have about 10 SQL servers that are all remote, we need to issue the same select statement on each SQL database which i have done just fine, this issue is we need to put the results from each select query on each different database to a central DB. Idealy it would be     Select [groupANames] into NewTableOnRemoteSQL From [OtherRemoteSqlDB].[Tablex].

Every remote DB of the 10 have different entries and I want the PS script to consolidate the results into another DB

So far i have been doing this by dumping the results into CSV's